# Private property in the class with Implements

Tags: vba, oop

I am trying to use some Object Oriented Programming principles but I am not sure if I am doing it right. I have created Interface class, let's name it lMyInterface and declared object variable there:

```
Dim rngSource as Range
```

Then in other class module, let's name it MyClass, I generated code as below:

```
Private Property Set IMyInterface_rngSource(RHS As Variant)
    Set lMeasureByRegion_rngSource = RHS
End Property
```

What should I do with this? I cannot use private property in the module. Should I write public property or function in MyClass that uses IMyInterface_rngSource or there is another way? 
I try to find out how could I benefit from using interfaces in VBA, if it is really useful function or just overkill.

Comment: Have you researched this (google)? I search the term "VBA interface example" and immediately get any number of useful "hits"...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP apparently hasn't done any basic research, such a googling the topic.

Comment: I wouldn't ask any question without spending a few hours googling.